# How to set height of TinyMce editor in Ext Js 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, tinymce

I am using TinyMce editor with Ext Js 4.1. It's works fine but problem is that initially height is more than I specify in view but after change tab  two times it's look fine. can any one guess what is the problem with height?

**for your information** : more than one TinyMce editor object and all are in model window with anchor layout with 100% anchor.

Comment: do you have a live example?

Comment: yes,Youe can check here,http://blogs.byte-force.com/xor/tinymce/  ,Here also same problem,click on open demo button and you can see window with tinymce

Comment: +1 thx, for this live example ...  makes it much easier to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should set

```
        width: 600,
        height: 500,
```

to the editor itself:

```
            items: [
            {
                xtype: "tinymce",
                tinymceSettings: {
                    theme : "advanced",
                    ...
                    width: 600,
                    height: 500,
                    ...
                },
                value: "<h1>Demo</h1><p>Ext.ux.TinyMCE works...</p>"
            }
```

Comment: I do exactly but it take more than 500px first time .that is actual problem.

Comment: what browser (and version are you using?) - with FF18 i do not get this effect

Comment: I am using chorme,but I checked it with safari and ff18 also. I got the issues also. and I found somebody post bug in tinymce forum but I think still it unsolved.

Comment: hmm, when i open the demo i get a window 600x500 pixels as expected

Comment: window works fine.My meaning was editor size is more than we specified,in this case our editor's bottom is now display properly.

Comment: If I choose less then 500 then after resize window it become less then  500 and that is not a goal.

Comment: hmm, you could write an own function that you call onInit of the editor which takes care of the correct size. I did that once.